Why is the #16 always left open?
In the 1974 film "Murder on the Orient Express" it is stated that compartment #16 is always left open. If I remember correctly, this is stated both at dinner and then again when Poirot and Bianchi (the director of the line) reach the train.
This is also stated in the book, which I am looking at now, where M. Bouc (the director of the railway) says to the conductor "He (Poirot) is a friend of mine. He can have the No. 16." and then when told that compartment is taken, M. Bouc replies "What? The No. 16?"
It may also be noted in the 2017 version of this film, although I am not familiar with this version.
My question is, why is the No. 16 supposedly always left open/available? Surely it wasn't a normal practice to leave an empty compartment in a passenger train like this? Is this the railway version of a Bridal Suite or Presidential Suite?

From the 2017 movie it's stated that the cabin is left for "official use".

BOUC: We shall make space. He can have the Number 16. The 16 is always left open
for official use. Very comfortable.

This seems not unreasonable as the company might wish to have a cabin available for VIPs or company officials wishing to travel at the last minute.
It's not unlike some hotels having special rooms or theatres with special seats that are not generally available until it's established they are not needed for special guests.
However, it does seem that the cabin can be used since in both the novel and the movies it has been booked. In the novel, it seems to me that the implication is that the conductor may have taken a bribe to make this available.

“It is taken, Monsieur.”
“What? The No. 16?”
A glance of understanding passed between them, and the conductor smiled. He was a tall sallow man of middle age.
Murder on the Orient Express - Agatha Christie


Thank you! I should have guessed that the answer was in the version I was least familiar with!

Also note that such luxury train compartments can be booked weeks or maybe even months in advance, so it is reasonable to keep one free for last-minute bookings. If no VIPs or company officials need to travel, they can theoretically still be sold on the last day.

it seems to me that the implication is that the conductor may have taken a bribe to make this available.
I'll not spoil it but anyone who gets to the end finds why the cabin was taken.
